# wx.RB_SINGLE makes button unable to be deselected with wxPython

Tags: gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets

According to the wxWidgets docs[1](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_radio_button.html), `wxRB_SINGLE` requires the programmer to manually handle selecting and deselecting radio buttons from the event handler for the button. However, try as I might, wxPython doesn't let me do that. I tried both directly calling `SetValue(False)` on the radio button and calling the same function from the `wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON` handler, but regardless the radio button stays selected and `GetValue()` returns True. What gives? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about `wx.RB_SINGLE`?

To clarify, my goal is to have radio buttons that — from the programmer's perspective — function like checkboxes. I want to handle their exact behaviour myself. I don't want any automatic grouping done by wxWidgets.

Here is the code I've been using to debug this:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        rb1 = wx.RadioButton(panel,
                                  label = 'Button 1',
                                  pos = (30, 10),
                                  style=wx.RB_SINGLE
                                  )
        rb2 = wx.RadioButton(panel,
                                  label = 'Button 2',
                                  pos = (30, 30),
                                  style=wx.RB_SINGLE
                                  )
        rb3 = wx.RadioButton(panel,
                                  label = 'Button 3',
                                  pos = (30, 50),
                                  style=wx.RB_SINGLE
                                  )
        rb2.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, lambda x: rb2.SetValue(False))
        rb2.SetValue(False)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For what it's worth, I'm using Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS with the GTK (version 3.24.33-1ubuntu2) backend for wxWidgets (via wxPython 4.2.0) running on Python 3.10.6.

Comment: I'm not sure about GTK but at least under MSW focused radio button is *always* checked. So you can only uncheck a radio button if it doesn't currently have focus -- and it will become checked if it gets focus.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but your design will confuse users. They will not expect the radio button to behave like a checkbox. The user will be able to select the RadioButton but not be able to deselect it. I use your type of design for radio buttons that never receive focus (greyed-out radio buttons with a state my code controls).

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry, I should've written it clearer. The radio button will not work as a checkbox from a user's perspective but rather the programmer's perspective, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Newbyte, why not use wxCheckBox?

Comment: @Igor Because from a user's perspective, it will act like a radio button.

Comment: @Newbyte, no it doesn't. There is a clear understanding and split - radio button should be radio button and check box should be check box. Why do you want to mix them up? But more importantly - nobody cares about the programmer, you as a developer should only be concern about the end user . Can you clearly explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Igor What I am trying to say is that for the user, it will act exactly as if the radio buttons were grouped. I just want the programmer-facing API to behave like a checkbox so that I can handle the mutually exclusive selection logic instead of wxWidgets/GTK doing it. The exact use-case is a wrapper library for wxWidgets that handles button grouping in a different manner (based on the value of a "source" variable which the widget is associated with). This is already implemented working, and used in production for Windows.

Comment: @Newbyte, ok, but why not use wxCheckBox? What prevents you from using it? You can place couple of wxCheckBox inside the box sizer and pretend that it is the wxRadioBox.  Why your softwatre needs to emulate something that is already present? What will you gain?

Comment: @Igor Because, again, from the user's perspective it will behave like a radio button and not a checkbox, so having it look like a checkbox would be confusing. I explained my use-case in the comment you replied to. It may be possible to rework the logic to not need `wx.RB_SINGLE`, but the current logic is battle-tested and works well on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in wxGTK. I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/pull/23677) to fix this, which according to the maintainer's comments seems like it will be merged for wxWidgets 3.3.0 (it was also backported to the 3.2 series in 3.2.4). If you're using an older version, I don't know of any workaround unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're out of luck, that style seems like an ill thought out option, because it clearly doesn't work, as you'd expect it to.
Your options are limited to a `wx.CheckBox` or you could look at an alternative `onoffbutton.py` available here:
https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/an-on-off-button-alternative-to-checkbox/36304/19

Spolier alert, I'm the author.
It has a variety of Radio type on/off buttons - get the zip file from the last post on the thread.